# Variable usable in Service

Tags: php, symfony, variables

I am a beginner in php. I have a `WadoService` service and a `StudiesRestController` controller. I want to use controller data in the service.

```
public function getPatientAction(Request $request, $studyUID)
{
    $studyRepository = new StudyRepository(
        $this->get('nexus_db'),
        $this->get('logger'),
        $this->get('translator')
    );

    $study = $studyRepository->getStudy($studyUID);
    if (!$study) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("No study found with studyuid $studyUID");
    }

    $patientInfo = new RestResponse(
        SerializerBuilder::create()
            ->build()
            ->serialize($study->getPatient(), 'json')
    );

    return $patientInfo;
}
```

Is this possible? I have tried to put this in the function `getPatientAction()`without result:

```
/* @var $wadoService WadoService */
    $wadoService = $this->container->get(WadoService::SERVICE_NAME);

   $wadoService = new RestResponse(
        SerializerBuilder::create()
            ->build()
            ->serialize($study->getPatient(), 'json')
    );
```

Comment: which technology are you using ? Drupal 8 ? Symfony ? Laravel ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. The code example you posted does not look relevant to the question.

Comment: @teeyo
I use Symfony.

Comment: @SirDarius
Sorry this is not necessarily very clear for me either ..
I want to be able to use data from my controller in my service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a variable from your controller to your service, you do it it like that :

```
$wadoService = $this->container->get(WadoService::SERVICE_NAME)->yourServiceMethod($yourVari);
```

Comment: I wnat to use the variable `$patientInfo` in my service. I need to do like this ? `$wadoService = $this->container->get(WadoService::SERVICE_NAME); 
 $wadoService->getPatientInfo($patientInfo);`